# JSON.parse Syntax Error with Button addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

When I run this code, I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at HTMLButtonElement.button.addEventListener (app.js:20)

app.js:6 is the line that reads "let userInfo = JSON.parse(jsonUser.responseText);

Why is the jsonUser variable not being pushed into the userInfo variable? When I run the code line-by-line in the console it works, but when I assign it to the button click it returns that error.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
//Get information about where the data is coming from
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let jsonUser = $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json');
    console.log(jsonUser);
    let userInfo = JSON.parse(jsonUser.responseText);
    let ip = userInfo.ip;
    let country = userInfo.country;
    let region = userInfo.region;
    let city = userInfo.city;
    let isp = userInfo.org;
    let zipcode = userInfo.postal;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<!--
Compressed jQuery Min v3.2.1 - 70 KB
-->
<title>Test Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">Test Complete</button>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json');` is asynchronous. it returns a jqXHR, that at some point in the futurue will have a responseText property. However, on the next line in the script, said property won't exist yet. When you run it line by line, by the time you run the line after it, it has had time to finish and thus has the property.

Comment: check the header Content-Type in response payload. Is application/json or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to parse before it's downloaded. Use the callback to wait until it's downloaded and then grab the data you need.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let jsonUser = $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json', function(userInfo) {
  let ip = userInfo.ip;
  let country = userInfo.country;
  let region = userInfo.region;
  let city = userInfo.city;
  let isp = userInfo.org;
  let zipcode = userInfo.postal;
  console.log(ip, country, region, city, isp, zipcode);
  });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
Compressed jQuery Min v3.2.1 - 70 KB
-->
  <title>Test Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button">Test Complete</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't wait for .getJSON to complete before moving on. So you need a callback function to use AFTER the data has been obtained from the URL. Like this:

```
var jsonUser;
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json', function(data){
    jsonUser=data;
    console.log(jsonUser);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
$.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io/json")
  .done(function( json ) {
    console.log(json);
    let userInfo = json; //JSON.parse(json)
    let ip = userInfo.ip;
    let country = userInfo.country;
    let region = userInfo.region;
    let city = userInfo.city;
    let isp = userInfo.org;
    let zipcode = userInfo.postal;
  });
});
```